# Showing category images on homepage menu in Opencart

Tags: opencart

all!
I downloaded my template and pasted code in file - /catalog/controller/common/header.php

```
// Level 1
        $this->load->model('tool/image');
        $image = empty($category['image']) ? 'no_image.jpg' : $category['image'];
        $thumb = $this->model_tool_image->resize($image, 100, 100);

        $this->data['categories'][] = array(
            'name'     => $category['name'],
            'children' => $children_data,
            'column'   => $category['column'] ? $category['column'] : 1,
            'thumb'    => $thumb,
            'href'     => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $category['category_id'])
        );
```

then pasted in /catalog/view/theme/freetemplate/template/common/header.tpl - this code

```
<img src="<?php echo $category['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $category['name']; ?>" title="<?php echo $category['name']; ?>" class="img-responsive" />
```

images - not show -

> Notice: Undefined variable: thumb ...

If I use default template - images in category menu - display.
Where I made a mistake?

Comment: Which version of Opencart? Where do you have pasted the codes? and what is full error?

Comment: Version 2.0.1.1, code pasted header.php and header.tpl mytemplate

Comment: <b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: thumb in <b>D:\www\freezepoint.juka.ua\catalog\view\theme\theme574\template\common\header.tpl</b>

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code with opencart 1 and its default theme, it worked.

As you are using opencart 2 you must change `$this->data` to `$data`:

```
$data['categories'][] = array(
```

Now it works for me on opencart 2.

Comment: if i used this code in 2.2.x that images - display. I changed how you said - but not work. And if i created any variable in /language/common/header.php for example $_['text_my'] = 'Welcome'; and load in /controller/common/header.php - $data['text_my'] = $this->language->get('text_my') and pasted in header.tpl - i get error - undefined variable: text_my..... ,at the same time all default variable example - $_['text_home']          = 'Home' - correctly show.

Comment: i guess that file in view/theme/mytempale/template/common/header.tpl not correctly bound with header.php

Comment: I have no idea about your custom theme, but that the way it is, and it works in default theme, could you post full code of both `header.php` and `header.tpl`?

Comment: If we have private message here, yes, send me.

Comment: I found. In this current template also necessary declare variables in file - /system/modification/catalog/controller/common/header.php and everything works!

Comment: Thank Mojtaba Sabeti that was not indifferent to my question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
Also necessary declare variables in file - /system/modification/catalog/controller/common/header.php and everything works!